# Deployed React app to Render, works fine locally, once deployed the URL changes but page doesn't update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My React app works fine locally, but once deployed, when I click links the URL changes but the page doesn't update. It will only update if I manually refresh the page after the URL changes.

I have no errors in the console and I am using version 18.2.0 of react and version 6.12.1 of react-router-dom.

I've tried every solution I could find in Google search but still can't resolve this. Any help would be appreciated.

My App.js:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navigation from './components/Navigation';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import Details from './pages/Details';
import About from './pages/About';

function App() {
    return (
        <>
            <Router>
                <Navigation />
                <Container>
                    <Routes>
                        <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
                        <Route path="/locations/:locationId" element={<Details />} />
                        <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
                    </Routes>
                </Container>
            </Router>
        </>
    );
}

export default App;
```

and my index.js looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from './app/store';
import App from './App';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './index.css';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

EDIT: I resolved this by updating my react router module to the latest version.

Comment: Did you face this problem when you navigate to any pages?
Or special one?

Comment: Any link does this, here is the live site: https://loc8r-mx4e.onrender.com/   For example, the about page isn't accepting any parameters or doing anything special and it has the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by updating my react router modules to the latest version.